# How to send float values from one arduino to another using xbee

Tags: arrays, arduino, xbee

I want to send three float values stored in an array(Eg:11.123456, 77.123456,60.00) from one arduino to another arduino using xbee in AT mode. And also I want to store those received values again in an array.

Please help me with the code.

Transmitter’s code:

```
void setup()
{
Serial.begin(115200);
Serial.write((uint8_t*)transmit, 3 * sizeof(float));
}
void loop()
{
   float transmit[3]={72.453444,83.345678,60}; //Values to be sent
}
```

Receiver’s code:

```
  #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
 #include <TinyGPS.h>
 TinyGPS gps;
 SoftwareSerial serialgps(2,3);
 #include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 7, 6,5, 4);
float b[3],latitude, longitude; 
int i;
void setup() 
{
Serial.begin(9600);
lcd.begin(16, 2);
lcd.setCursor(0,0);
lcd.print("  SMART ENGINE");
 delay(2000);
lcd.clear();

lcd.setCursor(0,0);
lcd.print("Happy Journey");
delay(1000); 
} 

void loop()
{
if(serialgps.available()>0)
{
 {
   Gpsgetdata();
 }

      if(Serial.available() >= 3 * sizeof(float))
        {
          Serialavailable();
        }
 }
 }

void Gpsgetdata()
{
int c = serialgps.read(); 
if(gps.encode(c)) 
lcd.print("Aquiring Location"); 
 {
gps.f_get_position(&latitude, &longitude);
}
}


void Serialavailable()
{
lcd.setCursor(0,0);
{
    uint8_t *recv_bytes = (uint8_t*)b;
    for(i=0; i < 3 * sizeof(float); i++)
    {
        recv_bytes[i] = Serial.read();
    }
 int a=0;
 float lati=b[0];
 float lon =b[1];
 a=b[2];
 delay(1000);
 if(a>=10&&lati>=10&&lon>=10)
 {
    lcd.clear();  
 for(int z=b[2];z>=15;z--)
 {
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Please wait for:");
      lcd.setCursor(4,1);
        lcd.print("Seconds");
          lcd.setCursor(0,1);
           lcd.print(z);
            delay(1000);
 }
      }
}
while(Serial.available())
Serial.read();
lcd.clear();
setup();

}
```

Comment: Hi Krish, you must try something by yourself, and show us (in your question) how far you got. Then we can help quicker.

Comment: Your problem is not clear. Do you have trouble sending or receiving? Btw your declaring transmit array after sending it, thats obviously not going to work. Could you be more specific please. I think I could help you.